# Video card like frying pan (heating)

Tags: video, cpu, sensors

I've installed the new Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Unity) and sensors.

This is what the sensors command gave me:

```
acpitz-virtual-0 Adapter: Virtual device temp1:        +64.0°C  (crit
= +89.0°C) temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +89.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100  Adapter: PCI adapter temp1:        +66.0°C  (high =
+95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C) 

coretemp-isa-0000 Adapter: ISA adapter Physical id 0:  +65.0°C  (high
= +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C) Core 0:         +65.0°C  (high = 
+80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C) Core 1:         +63.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit =
+85.0°C)
```

But I actually have 4 cores, and the temperature is too high as for me.

Should I worry about that?

Comment: Is this the temperature when you're playing games or otherwise at load, or just sitting idle? It doesn't seem like an unreasonable temperature, from what I'm seeing online.

Comment: That time was Firefox opened with 10-15 tabs.

Answer (score 0):

From discussions on various forums, the consensus online seems to be that ~65 degrees C is an OK temperature for a video card, and is certainly not dangerous for the hardware.

Here's one explanation of temperature on the infamous Tom's Hardware forum:

> Anything below 90C would not damage the card. The ideal is to have it below 80C and the best is for it not to run over 70C [...] It should be fine. Don't worry about temperature until it reach over 80C and around 50C when idle.

http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1744939/safe-graphics-card-temperature.html

On this forum, some users report temperatures of 60 degrees C even when the graphics card isn't doing anything (is idle): 
http://www.gamespot.com/forums/pc-mac-linux-society-1000004/whats-average-graphics-card-temperature-25886452/

If you'd like to lower the temperature of the graphics card, the easiest effective way is to open up your computer and blow out the dust! Also make sure there is nothing blocking the airflow both inside and outside your computer.